# eclipse ide Check For Updates fails

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Every time I try to install updates on to eclipse ide it fails with constraint validation error. E.g. eclipse shows me list of plugins which needs to be updated, I select them all and on the pahase of constraint checking it fails saying that only one version of a plugin can be installed.

How to fix it?

**UPD**

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: CDO Model Repository Server 4.0.0.v20110831-1303 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.feature.group 4.0.0.v20110831-1303)
  Software being installed: CDO Model Repository Server Hibernate 2.0.0.v200906221520 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.hibernate.feature.group 2.0.0.v200906221520)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    CDO Model Repository Client 2.0.0.v200906160459 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo 2.0.0.v200906160459)
    CDO Model Repository Client 4.0.1.v20110831-1303 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo 4.0.1.v20110831-1303)
    CDO Model Repository Client 4.0.0.v20110608-1639 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo 4.0.0.v20110608-1639)
    CDO Model Repository Client 2.0.0.v200906221520 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo 2.0.0.v200906221520)
    CDO Model Repository Client 1.0.9.v200902280039 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo 1.0.9.v200902280039)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CDO Model Repository Server 2.0.0.v200906160459 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server 2.0.0.v200906160459)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.cdo [2.0.0,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CDO Model Repository Server 2.0.0.v200906221520 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server 2.0.0.v200906221520)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.cdo [2.0.0,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CDO Model Repository Server 4.0.0.v20110831-1303 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.feature.group 4.0.0.v20110831-1303)
    To: org.eclipse.emf.cdo [4.0.1.v20110831-1303]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CDO Model Repository Server Hibernate 2.0.0.v200906221520 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.hibernate 2.0.0.v200906221520)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server [2.0.0,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CDO Model Repository Server Hibernate 2.0.0.v200906221520 (org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.hibernate.feature.group 2.0.0.v200906221520)
    To: org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.hibernate [2.0.0.v200906221520]
```

Comment: There might be dependecy. Update one by one and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constraint means that during the update the system has found incompatible versions of plug-ins: they are depending on the same plug-in.

Check the Error log view of the Eclipse where you can find a more detailed message from that you can trace back the offending plug-in (it is not the simplest description possible to determine the conflicting plug-ins, but I don't know of any other type of p2 update logger facility).

**EDIT**: It seems to me from checking the error message, that the update found an update for the CDO Model Repository CLient, but did not for the Repository Server Hibernate Component. I would try to add the CDO 4.0-corresponding update site location from http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDO/Hibernate_Store/Download_and_Install#Update_site_locations (at least if this is what you use for Hibernate support in COD).

Otherwise I would try (after backing up your Eclipse folder) to uninstall the Hibernate component, and then update, then finding the correct location of the CDO Hibernate component you are using.

Comment: Updated question with error explanation,what are my actions to resolve this problem?